# Hex addition in C++

Tags: c++

I want to add an array in Hex. I have done this but I am facing problems in the addition function; it is not adding but showing some pictures.

```
void addition(char hexDecOne[10], char hexDecTwo[10], char (&hexDecSum)[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // convert to decimal and add both array values
        hexDecSum[i] = convert(hexDecOne[i]) + convert(hexDecTwo[i]);
        // add values and if they are greater than F add 1 to next value
        hexDecSum[i + 1] += hexDecSum[i] / 16;
        hexDecSum[i] %= 16;
    }
}

int convert(char item) {
    switch (item) {
        case 'A':
            return 10;
            break;
        case 'B':
            return 11;
            break;
        case 'C':
            return 12;
            break;
        case 'D':
            return 13;
            break;
        case 'E':
            return 14;
            break;
        case 'F':
            return 15;
            break;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: IMO a better approach is to convert your numbers to base 10, perform the mathematical operation in native arithmetic, then convert the result.

Comment: Where does it show "pictures"?

Comment: I am supposed to add a digit upto 10 digits, that is not posible in int #Bathsheba

Comment: @UsamaNadeem:  So use an `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t` then.

Comment: @UsamaNadeem: How would you add "FF" and "FF"? Or even "FF" and "01"? Your algorithm would fail.

Comment: @UsamaNadeem, in which case, use int64_t as your type.

Comment: @Bathsheba:  He'd be better converting the hex string to an integer type not "base 10".

Comment: @Clifford: Looks like homework to implement hex addition algorithm not just use plus operator

Comment: @UsamaNadeem: Your result may have more than 10 hex digits. As for convert func - hex digits are not only A-F but 0-9A-F

Comment: @UsamaNadeem: Of course you are aware that you add left to right and should right to left so if you just store reversed - you must print reverse of your result too when printing.

Comment: @Artur: I'm sure it is.  I was responding to the comment (the flawed reasoning that it could not be done due to data type size), rather than the original question. It is for Usama to determine whether the suggestion is useful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing various ways of doing this and so far no-one mentioned the obvious, inbuilt functionality:: I have included a `stringstream` way of manipulating hex character arrays and use of `std::dec` and `std::hex` to convert between hex and decimal.  Using the code below I think you could alter your code easily to incorporate the inbuilt functionality available.

I have changed the code a little to further illustrate usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    const char* test = "deadbeef"; // or indeed you could pass in any array of char
    unsigned int x;
    std::stringstream ss;          // set up a stringstream object to use for conversions 
    ss << std::hex << test;        // put the value held by test into the stringstream, telling the stringstream its a hex value
    ss >> x;                       // put the value held by the stringstream into x (now a decimal)
    std::cout << "as an unsigned value: "<< x<<std::endl;    // output it as an usigned int
    std::cout << "as a signed value" <<static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl; // output it as signed int
    // now we can use similar functionality with inputs from the user
    int input ;
    std::cout << "Enter decimal number: " ;
    std::cin >> input ;
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << input << std::endl ;
    std::string inpStr;
    std::cout << "Please input a hex string without the preceding 0x:";
    std::cin >> inpStr;
    std::stringstream ss2;
    ss2 << std::hex <<inpStr;
    ss2 >> x;
    std::cout << "The value of 0x" <<inpStr<<" in hex is actually: "<< std::dec << x << " in decimal\n";
    // to do additions try the following:
    int firstInt = 0xab;
    int secInt = 0xff;
    std::cout << "the values 0xab + 0xff = 0x" <<std::hex << (firstInt+secInt);
    std::cout << " and in decimal: "<< std::dec << firstInt << "+" << secInt << "= "<< (firstInt+secInt);

    return x;
}
```

This code outputs the following when 256 and ff are entered as the values at the command line:

```
as an unsigned value: 3735928559
as a signed value-559038737
Enter decimal number: 256
0x100
Please input a hex string without the preceding 0x: ff
The value of 0xff in hex is actually: 255 in decimal
the values 0xab + 0xff = 0x1aa and in decimal: 171+255= 426
```

That should allow you to easily carry out mathematical operations on hex values:)

Let me know if you need more information.:)

Comment: Some constructive criticism would have been appreciated,  rather than a down vote sans reason.  Let me know and I can improve the answer

Answer (score 3):

Your "digits" stored in `hexDecOne` and `hexDecTwo` aren't hexadecimal digits, they are characters equal to `'0'`, `'1'`, etc until `'F'`. Your `convert` function needs to convert characters `'0'` to `'9'` as well, and after that you need to convert your result the other way around for your digits to appear as characters.

By the way,your code creates a buffer overflow when the addition of the most significant digits of the two `hexDec` implies a non-nul carry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `convert` function to handle `0`..`9` as well as `A`..`F`:

```
unsigned short convert(char item) {
    if (item >= 'A' && item <= 'F') 
        return static_cast<unsigned short>('A' - item + 10);
    else if (item >= '0' && item <= '9')
        return static_cast<unsigned short>('0' - item);
    else // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <map>
 #include <cctype>
 #include <algorithm>

 using namespace std;

 int convert2i(char item) {
     static bool isFirst = true;
     static map<char, int>lookup;
     if(isFirst){
         for(int i=0;i<16;++i)
             lookup["0123456789ABCDEF"[i]]=i;
         isFirst = false;
     }
     return lookup[::toupper(item)];
 }

 char convert2C(int num){
     static bool isFirst = true;
     static map<int, char>lookup;
     if(isFirst){
         for(int i=0;i<16;++i)
             lookup[i]="0123456789ABCDEF"[i];
         isFirst = false;
     }
     return 0 <= num && num <= 15 ? lookup[num] : -1;
 }

 void addition(char hexDecOne[10], char hexDecTwo[10], char (&hexDecSum)[10]) {
     int carry = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {// 9 : 10-1 (-1 for EOS)
         int wk = convert2i(hexDecOne[i]) + convert2i(hexDecTwo[i]) + carry;
         if(wk < 16){
             carry = 0;
         } else {
             carry = 1;
             wk -= 16;
         }
         hexDecSum[i] = convert2C(wk);
     }
     if(carry)
         cerr << "overflow in addition" << endl;
 }

 int main(void){
     char hex1[10] = "ABC000000";
     char hex2[10] = "FED000000";
     char sum[10];

     addition(hex1, hex2, sum);
     reverse(sum, sum+sizeof(sum)-1);//reverse(&sum[0], &sum[9]);//[0,9)
     cout << string(sum) << endl;//000001AA9
 }
```

Comment: Not only is this code incorrect (see: http://ideone.com/MEYnIg) but it offers no explanation as to how it fixes the original problem.

Comment: @Johnsyweb (saw ideone) It will give the correct answer. (000000001+ 00000000F=000000010, 100000000+F00000000=>overflow) You're misunderstanding. You should be aware of the hex format of this case though it is reverse order. array[0] mean the lowest.

Comment: If not is there a meaning to reverse for display?

Comment: There is no meaning to write comments like this, `i=5;//assign 5 to variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example solution of 'manual' hex addition:

```
char hexOne[8];
char hexTwo[8];
char hexSum[9];

int char2dec(char hex_char)
{
    // assume 0-9A-F input - no error handling

    if ((hex_char >= '0') && (hex_char <= '9'))
    {
        return hex_char - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        return hex_char - 'A' + 10;
    }
}

char dec2char(int dec)
{
    // assume 0-15 input - no error handling
    return "0123456789ABCDEF"[dec];
}

void addHex(char hexOne[8], char hexTwo[8], char hexSum[9])
{
    char carry = '0';
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        char sum = char2dec(hexOne[i]) + char2dec(hexTwo[i]) + char2dec(carry);
        carry = dec2char(sum / 16);
        sum  = sum % 16;

        hexSum[i] = dec2char(sum);
    }

    if (carry != '0') hexSum[i] = carry;
}

void printHexWithoutCarry(char hex[])
{
    char print = 0;
    printf("0x");

    for(int digit = 7; digit >= 0; digit--)
    {
        // skip 0s
        if (digit)
        {
            if ( hex[digit] != '0' ) print = 1;
        } 
        else
        {
            print = 1;
        }

        if (print)
        {
            printf("%c", hex[digit]);
        }
    }
}

void encodeAsHexArray(int val, char dst[])
{
    for(int digit = 0; digit < 8; digit++)
    {
        char tmp = val & 0xF;
        dst[digit] = dec2char(tmp);
        val >>= 4;
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    encodeAsHexArray(0xFF, hexOne);
    encodeAsHexArray(0x1, hexTwo);

    printHexWithoutCarry(hexOne); printf("\n");
    printHexWithoutCarry(hexTwo); printf("\n");
    addHex(hexOne, hexTwo, hexSum);
    printHexWithoutCarry(hexSum);
}
```

result:

```
0xFF
0x1
0x100
```

Answer (score 0):

For large hex number, here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string plus_hex(string hex1, string hex2)
{
    if (hex1.length() < hex2.length())
        hex1.swap(hex2);

    //for convenience, make sure that hex1 is longer.

    /*Strat algorithm*/

    int length1, length2;
    length1 = hex1.length();
    length2 = hex2.length();
    int flag = 0; // carry
    int get1, get2;
    int sum;

    while (length1>0)
    {
        //get first number
        if (hex1[length1 - 1] >= 'A')
            get1 = hex1[length1 - 1] - 55;
        else
            get1 = hex1[length1 - 1] - '0';

        //get second number

        if (length2 > 0)
        {
            if (hex2[length2 - 1] >= 'A')
                get2 = hex2[length2 - 1] - 55;
            else
                get2 = hex2[length2 - 1] - '0';
        }
        else
            get2 = 0;

        //get the sum
        sum = get1 + get2 + flag;

        if (sum >= 16)
        {
            int left = sum % 16;
            if (left >= 10)
                hex1[length1 - 1] = 'A' + left % 10;
            else
                hex1[length1 - 1] = '0' + left;
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sum >= 10)
                hex1[length1 - 1] = 'A' + sum % 10;
            else
                hex1[length1 - 1] = '0' + sum;
            flag = 0;
        }

        length1--;
        length2--;
    }

    if (flag == 1)
        return "1" + hex1;
    else
        return hex1;

    /*End of algorithm*/
}
int main(void)
{
    string hex1, hex2;

    while (cin >> hex1 >> hex2)
        cout << plus_hex(hex1, hex2);

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
For example:

FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
1
```

Result:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000
```